# How to organize a python project with poetry for a command line script

Tags: python, python-poetry

When doing a poetry init I got the following structure:

```
/packagename
  __init__.py
  packagename.py
 /packagename
  /tests
   __init__.py
   test_packagename.py
pyproject.toml
```

which is fine for a package but I do not see how to make it fit a command line script.
When I have a script like script.py with the following code structure:

In file script.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

def main():
  print("Ok")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

It is not intended to be used as a python module however, it may have dependencies and tests that are interesting to be handle with poetry.

In some [example](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-write-python-command-line-interfaces-like-a-pro-f782450caf0d) it is shown that with the following poetry syntax:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
cli_script = 'script.py:main'
```

then one can call the script with:

```
poetry run cli_script
```

I am looking for some guideline on howto organize properly my poetry project for such usage.

I have looked for option for poetry init (like poetry init --script) for instance. But it seems that kind of use case was not covered in the new/init poetry options.

Answer (score 16):

By "poetry init" I guess you mean `poetry new`. But also then your structure looks a bit weird. I would suggest the following structure:

```sh
packagename
├── packagename
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── cli.py
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_packagename.py
└── pyproject.toml
```

The `pyproject.toml` looks like this:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "packagename"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["finswimmer <finswimmer@example.org>"]

[tool.poetry.scripts]
cli_script = "packagename.cli:main"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.6"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^5.2"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry>=1.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.masonry.api"
```

You `cli.py` as in your example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

def main():
  print("Ok")

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

After a `poetry install` you can run `poetry run cli_script`.

Comment: And after `poetry install` I believe you should also just be able to run `cli_script`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can run:

```
poetry run python3 script.py
```

where:

- `script.py` is the name of the file having python code.
- `python3` is the python executable inside the poetry virtual environment. This can be `python` as well, depending on the python version you have. You may confirm the same using `poetry run python3 -V` or `poetry run python -V`, before executing the above command.

This command can be used in `crontab` as well to schedule simple scripts.